# matplotlib figure parameters don't appears

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

Here is my issue: I have an embedded matplotlib figure in a Qt5 application. When I press the button "edit axis, curve and image parameter", I select my concerned subplot, but only the tab "axis" options appears. it is missing tabs for "curve" and "image".

actual picture

[image]

whereas I should have had something like this:

targeted picture

[image]

If anyone knows why...

Comment: show your code!!!!!

Comment: Just a guess without having used mpl in a while, but iirc the tabs only show up if your plot/figure has those elements. If your test plot is just a line then it might not have those other settings.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the code, it is bellow

Answer (score 0):

Probably the answer is easy:

- If there is no curve (line) in the plot, there will be no "Curves" tab.
- If there is no image in the plot, there will be no "Images" tab.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is why I switch from pcolor to imshow

Answer (score 0):

class View2D(MapView):

```
def show(self, som, what='codebook', which_dim='all', cmap=None,
         col_sz=None, desnormalize=False):
    (self.width, self.height, indtoshow, no_row_in_plot, no_col_in_plot,
     axis_num) = self._calculate_figure_params(som, which_dim, col_sz)
    self.prepare()

    if not desnormalize:
        codebook = som.codebook.matrix
    else:
        codebook = som._normalizer.denormalize_by(som.data_raw, som.codebook.matrix)

    if which_dim == 'all':
        names = som._component_names[0]
    elif type(which_dim) == int:
        names = [som._component_names[0][which_dim]]
    elif type(which_dim) == list:
        names = som._component_names[0][which_dim]


    while axis_num < len(indtoshow):
        axis_num += 1
        ax = plt.subplot(no_row_in_plot, no_col_in_plot, axis_num)
        ind = int(indtoshow[axis_num-1])

        min_color_scale = np.mean(codebook[:, ind].flatten()) - 1 * np.std(codebook[:, ind].flatten())
        max_color_scale = np.mean(codebook[:, ind].flatten()) + 1 * np.std(codebook[:, ind].flatten())
        min_color_scale = min_color_scale if min_color_scale >= min(codebook[:, ind].flatten()) else \
            min(codebook[:, ind].flatten())
        max_color_scale = max_color_scale if max_color_scale <= max(codebook[:, ind].flatten()) else \
            max(codebook[:, ind].flatten())
        norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min_color_scale, vmax=max_color_scale, clip=True)

        mp = codebook[:, ind].reshape(som.codebook.mapsize[0],
                                      som.codebook.mapsize[1])
        # pl = plt.pcolor(mp[::-1], norm=norm, cmap='jet')  
        pl = plt.imshow(mp[::-1], interpolation='nearest', origin='lower',cmap='jet') 

        plt.axis([0, som.codebook.mapsize[1], 0, som.codebook.mapsize[0]])
        plt.title(names[axis_num - 1])
        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        plt.colorbar(pl)

    plt.show()
```